# Arduino Chain counter

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm planning to use the basic model of an arduino bike speedometer to count the amount of chain that I let out when I anchor my boat. However if I only have one sensor it would only work for the chain counting one way. 
My theory is to have two sensors on the wheel so that if sensor A counts first then the chain is going out but if sensor B is counts first then the chain is coming in.
Only problem is I am much better at coding in python than I am in the arduino IDE. I would be super grateful if someone could give me an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

From you application description, you really wan't to track the position of the wheel holding the chain, not the speed (or velocity).  If you read how rotary encoders work, you can apply that technique to the wheel.  Rotary encoders have two digital outputs which are out of phase by 90 degrees so you can not only detect motion, but direction.

See http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/RotaryEncoders for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be more useful to count chain out and count back in?

Only 1 magnet on the chain gypsy that counts out your chain from the stowed position,  picking up a 12v signal from the windlass direction solenoid lowering feed,  stores this value at rest. When raising pick another 12v from the windlass solenoid raising feed to count the value back down to zero at the rest position?

This negates the need to determine direction by interpreting motor direction as count positive and count negative IO signals?